Is it okay to use two circuit breakers in parallel knowing it's okay for one breaker to trip early?
I am building a battery pack for my solar system at home. I have everything I need except for the circuit breaker. My battery pack can safely output 300 A no problem at 51.2 V. I'm a bit stubborn and would really really want to use a miniature type circuit breaker (MCB) but reputable brand MCBs only goes upto 125 A. I don't trust these China brands that are listed 200-300 A MCB.
I was thinking that instead of using one MCB I'll use two. The MCB I have in mind is the C120N from Schneider. It can handle 125 A with a max 250 VDC (@10 kA breaking.)
I will be using two of these in parallel so I can have a total of 250 A which is a bit lower than the 300 A maximum for my battery pack, but I am fine with that as ideally I only want it to operate at a maximum of 200 A.
The potential problem I can think of doing it this way is having mismatch current, and one breaker trips earlier than the other. I'll be careful to match the resistance of the wiring, but I actually wouldn't mind taking this downside rather than using a much larger molded case circuit breaker (MCCB)
Aside from that is there any other reasons why I shouldn't do this?
I'm trying to sanity check myself.

The only reason to do that is if your local electrical code and inspector is OK with that. Does the electrical code allow it?

How about building multiple battery packs?

@Justme its a battery pack, from my interaction with them, they probably have no clue or do not care since its "not technically AC"

@greybeard I cant split the battery packs since its already in a 16-Series configuration cant make it smaller. Buying smaller capacity battery is also significantly more expensive compared to larger capacity ones.

@DrakeJest I am prettt sure even if AC mains code does not apply, some other electrical installation codes may apply. It can't be that anyone could do unsafe installations and that would be legally OK.

Those breakers have a DC breaking capacity listed, but "network type" is specified as "AC" only, so they may not be suitable for your application. In addition to the concerns already enumerated, I believe code (in the US) states that breakers on the same circuit must be physically connected to trip together. DIY is probably a better place for this question.

Paralleling circuit breakers is not recommended. One breaker will trip at its rated current and as soon as that side of the circuit is open the other breaker will trip. There can never be a realistic circuit build where everything is perfectly matched and as such the two circuit breakers will not split the load current evenly.

If that is the only concern, then im willing to take that risk, i mean the worst that can happen in that case is the battery gets disconnected at an earlier Amps which is not catastrophic. Also i highly doubt the imbalance of current is that much, my BMS will limit the current to 200A, is it really that likely that the current imbalance will be in the 50A range?

@DrakeJest - It all depends on the internal resistance of the 2 circuit breakers.  Since the two circuit breakers are going to have the same (small) voltage drop across them), the current each one is carrying is going to be inversely proportional to their internal resistances.  This is something I'm sure the manufacturer doesn't specify (except maybe as a worst case value), and so is something you should test for.

Practically speaking, since standard MCBs have a thermal element for the slow response, I would guess they are fairly well matched within the same part #.  But the only way to be sure would be to measure it.
